# UIActivityViewController - plugin net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension invalidated

Tags: ios, iphone, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` and after sending an image via Whatsapp, I'm getting this message in the console -

```
plugin net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension invalidated
```

Why is this message showing in log?

jaba edited -

*I am using iOS 9.2, Swift, Xcode 7.2.*

But i (oz) was using Xcode 6.4, objective-c, iOS 8

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Any work around?

Comment: I am also facing this issue, any update on this.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp has updated policies which doesn't allow simple text to be shared along with Image or URL or Document.

You can send the image this way:

```
NSMutableArray *activityItems= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:img, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePrint,                                                         UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,                                                         UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,                                                         UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,                                                         UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,UIActivityTypeAirDrop];    
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Also you would need to set permission in Plist file for iOS9**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>
```